# Weak reference related exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, weak-references, inflector

I started getting the exception below after starting to use a class from an open source MVVM framework that uses weak references to prevent memory leaks.

This class is called `PropertyObserver` and is "A standardized way to handle the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event of other objects. This class uses weak references and the weak-event pattern to prevent memory leaks."

The trigger for the exception was quitting a WPF app, in which a `ShellVm` has a reference to a `MasterVm` which has references to multiple `DetailVm`s, each of which holds the aforementioned `PropertyObserver`. The `MasterVm` is ultimately the consumer of the static `Inflector` class used to pluralize and capitalize this and that, which is where the `WeakReference` related exception gets thrown.

I can't say I fully understand the exception, so I guess that is the starting point. How would I start to resolve this?

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=Handle is not initialized.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.WeakReference.set_Target(Object value)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement, Int32 count, Int32 startat)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, String replacement)
   at Inflector.Inflector.Rule.Apply(String word)
   at Inflector.Inflector.ApplyRules(List`1 rules, String word)
   at Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(String word)
   at Smack.Core.Lib.TextUtil.StringEx.Pluralize(String s)
   at Smack.Core.Lib.TextUtil.StringEx.PluralizeWithCount[T](String s, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Smack.Core.Presentation.Wpf.ViewModels.MasterDetailVms.GenericMasterViewModel`2.get_Status()

InnerException:
```

Comment: what version of .NET do you use and what version uses that framework?

Comment: @Tigran. All of my assemblies are 4.0. I copied the code into an existing assembly, so no references to a framework dll for the PropertyObserver. The Inflector code that throws is in a dll, and likely an older version (not sure how to tell for sure though)

Comment: The exception is actually triggered by Regex, it also uses weak refs.  The stack trace is very incomplete.  Quacks like a bug in the library code.  Look for destructors being use inappropriately.

Comment: @HansPassant. That was it, some logging line in a destructor where a value was null - thank you!. Why not put this in an answer format so I can mark it as such? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Will try to give a suggession, as something like this I met many years ago. To be honest I didn't find a *real* solution for it. First a rough one, after just change an architecture.

I'm afraid there is no other solution, then just *try* to call GC.Collect() on destroying object (rough solution), or just change MVVM framework.

After googling some:

[Handle not initialized1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/99c42e3f-7014-4cb1-abed-da43e15d31f5)

[Handle not initialized2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97085/windows-forms-invalidoperationexception)

In short this is something related to `WeakReferences` bug present in different versions of `.NET Framework`.

Good luck.

Comment: That doesn't sound encouraging... sigh, another day

Comment: @Berryl: Sad, but true. May be you can download it, recompile under .NET 4.0, and hopefully "resolve" your problem...

Comment: I actually did that before I saw the comment from Hans. The problem was a rogue destructor that the WeakRef somehow exacerbated

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment:

> The exception is actually triggered by Regex, it also uses weak refs.
> The stack trace is very incomplete. Quacks like a bug in the library
> code. Look for destructors being use inappropriately.

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant),  [Sep 29, 2011 at 19:24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601746/weak-reference-related-exception#comment9223513_7601746)

---

And this was confirmed by the OP:

> That was it, some logging line in a destructor where a value was null

[Berryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95245/berryl), [Sep 29, 2011 at 20:54](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601746/weak-reference-related-exception#comment9224993_7601746)